# script for Running MPI program with three input files as command line arguments

Tags: bash

`enter code here` The MPI program takes 3 command line arguments (2 input files and SIZE which is same for pair of files). For example in the same directory i have these files.

```
abc.mtx,  abc.txt  SIZE is same for these 2 files

def.mtx,  def.txt  SIZE is same for these two files

qas.mtx,  qas.txt  SIZE is same for these two files

and so on .....
```

Please note: Name of files is same but extension is different.

i want to run my code as

```
mpirun -np 4 ./myexe file1.mtx file1.txt -SIZE 10  //.myexe is executable
```

I want to execute my program with the different number of processes say -np 2,4,6,8 and 10. I have more than a hundred files. I want to execute my code once from command line that reads these files one by one with the specified number of processes.

for example

```
abc.mtx and abc.txt should run first with 2,4,6,8,10 processes 

and then next two files def.mtx and def.txt with 2,4,6,8,10  processes and so on....
```

For serial code, I have tried the following command and it works by taking all .txt files one by one.( only for txt or mtx files but not both toegther)

```
find . -name "*.txt" | awk -F"/" '{system ("./myexe." $2)}'
```

How can i run with 2 input files with different extension i.e (mtx, txt). what is best way to go for third argument that is SIZE. Should i create another file which contains the SIZE and gives three input file arguments as input.?

EDIT
Here is a script

```
#!/bin/bash

while read base size; do
   mtx="${base}.mtx"
   txt="${base}.txt"
   for np in 2 4 6 8 10; do
      echo mpirun -np $np ./myexe "$mtx" "$txt" -SIZE $size
   done
done < jobs
```

jobs.txt file looks like

```
bus 490
bcs_B 10
arc 1178
tk18 99
```

I am using following command to execute

```
./script.sh jobs.txt ./new
```

also tried

```
bash script.sh jobs.txt ./new
```

EDIT 2

Jobs.txt looks like

```
494_bus 494
arc130 130
bcsstk02 66
bcsstk18 11948
```

script is

```
#!/bin/bash
while read base size; do
   mtx="${base}.mtx"
   txt="${base}.txt"
   for np in 2 4; do
      mpirun -np $np ./new "$txt" "$mtx" -SIZE $size
   done
done < "$1"
```

I am just printing the dimension of the matrix from my code. and the output is

```
Dimension of the matrix is = 494 
Dimension of the matrix is = 494 
Dimension of the matrix is = 494 
Dimension of the matrix is = 494 
Dimension of the matrix is = 494 
Dimension of the matrix is = 494
```

It only takes the first pair of files, execute them with -np 2 and -np 4 but doesn't execute the rest.

if i write Echo in the script before mpirun it shows

```
mpirun -np 2 ./new 494_bus.txt 494_bus.mtx -SIZE 494
mpirun -np 4 ./new 494_bus.txt 494_bus.mtx -SIZE 494
mpirun -np 2 ./new arc130.txt arc130.mtx -SIZE 130
mpirun -np 4 ./new arc130.txt arc130.mtx -SIZE 130
mpirun -np 2 ./new bcsstk02.txt bcsstk02.mtx -SIZE 66
mpirun -np 4 ./new bcsstk02.txt bcsstk02.mtx -SIZE 66
mpirun -np 2 ./new bcsstk18.txt bcsstk18.mtx -SIZE 11948
mpirun -np 4 ./new bcsstk18.txt bcsstk18.mtx -SIZE 11948
```

If i execute each of these commands separately they work fine. for example

```
mpirun -np 4 ./new arc130.txt arc130.mtx -SIZE 130
mpirun -np 2 ./new bcsstk18.txt bcsstk18.mtx -SIZE 11948
```

These run commands works fine but not running with the script.
Thanks

EDIT 3

```
cat jobs.txt 

494_bus 494
arc130 130
bcsstk02 66
bcsstk18 11948



cat -vet jobs.txt

494_bus 494$
arc130 130$
bcsstk02 66$
bcsstk18 11948$
```

cat script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

while read base size; do
   mtx="${base}.mtx"
   txt="${base}.txt"
   for np in 2 4; do
      mpirun -np $np ./new "$txt" "$mtx" -SIZE $size
   done
done < "$1"
```

cat -vet script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash$
$
while read base size; do$
   mtx="${base}.mtx"$
   txt="${base}.txt"$
   for np in 2 4; do$
      mpirun -np $np ./new "$txt" "$mtx" -SIZE $size$
   done$
done < "$1"$
```

EDIT 4

```
bash -xv script2.sh jobs.txt
#!/bin/bash

while read base size; do
   mtx="${base}.mtx"
   txt="${base}.txt"
   for np in 2 4; do
      mpirun -np $np ./new "$txt" "$mtx" -SIZE $size
   done
done < "$1"
+ read base size
+ mtx=494_bus.mtx
+ txt=494_bus.txt
+ for np in 2 4
+ mpirun -np 2 ./new 494_bus.txt 494_bus.mtx -SIZE 494
Dimension of the matrix is = 494 
Dimension of the matrix is = 494 
+ for np in 2 4
+ mpirun -np 4 ./new 494_bus.txt 494_bus.mtx -SIZE 494
Dimension of the matrix is = 494 
Dimension of the matrix is = 494 
Dimension of the matrix is = 494 
Dimension of the matrix is = 494 
+ read base size
```

Comment: I don't see any C....

Comment: nor really an MPI question ...

Comment: why the [batch-file] tag, when you obviously want `bash`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

I suspect the MPI program is consuming some/all of the `stdin`, so I propose reading the entire jobs list into a `bash` array:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read entire jobs file into array jobs[]
IFS=$'\n' jobs=($(cat "$1"))

for j in "${jobs[@]}"; do
   IFS=" " read base size <<< "$j"
   mtx="${base}.mtx"
   txt="${base}.txt"
   for np in 2 4 6 8 10; do
      echo mpirun -np $np ./myexe "$mtx" "$txt" -SIZE $size
   done
done
```

**Updated Answer**

In the light of your comments, the easiest is probably to have a file called `jobs` with content like this:

```
abc 108
def 120
qas 196
```

And the change the script so it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read base size; do
   mtx="${base}.mtx"
   txt="${base}.txt"
   for np in 2 4 6 8 10; do
      echo mpirun -np $np ./myexe "$mtx" "$txt" -SIZE $size
   done
done < "$1"
```

**Sample Output**

```
mpirun -np 2 ./myexe abc.mtx abc.txt -SIZE 108
mpirun -np 4 ./myexe abc.mtx abc.txt -SIZE 108
mpirun -np 6 ./myexe abc.mtx abc.txt -SIZE 108
mpirun -np 8 ./myexe abc.mtx abc.txt -SIZE 108
mpirun -np 10 ./myexe abc.mtx abc.txt -SIZE 108
mpirun -np 2 ./myexe def.mtx def.txt -SIZE 120
mpirun -np 4 ./myexe def.mtx def.txt -SIZE 120
mpirun -np 6 ./myexe def.mtx def.txt -SIZE 120
mpirun -np 8 ./myexe def.mtx def.txt -SIZE 120
mpirun -np 10 ./myexe def.mtx def.txt -SIZE 120
mpirun -np 2 ./myexe qas.mtx qas.txt -SIZE 196
mpirun -np 4 ./myexe qas.mtx qas.txt -SIZE 196
mpirun -np 6 ./myexe qas.mtx qas.txt -SIZE 196
mpirun -np 8 ./myexe qas.mtx qas.txt -SIZE 196
mpirun -np 10 ./myexe qas.mtx qas.txt -SIZE 196
```

---

**Original Answer**

Not sure why you have tagged this as `batch-file` (which is a nasty Windows thing) when you are using `awk` and `find`?

Anyway, this does what you seem to be asking:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.mtx; do
   # Get name of corresponding text file
   t="${f%.*}.txt"
   for np in 2 4 6 8 10; do
      echo mpirun -np $np ./myexe "$f" "$t" -SIZE 10
   done
done
```

**Sample Output**

```
mpirun -np 2 ./myexe abc.mtx abc.txt -SIZE 10
mpirun -np 4 ./myexe abc.mtx abc.txt -SIZE 10
mpirun -np 6 ./myexe abc.mtx abc.txt -SIZE 10
mpirun -np 8 ./myexe abc.mtx abc.txt -SIZE 10
mpirun -np 10 ./myexe abc.mtx abc.txt -SIZE 10
mpirun -np 2 ./myexe def.mtx def.txt -SIZE 10
mpirun -np 4 ./myexe def.mtx def.txt -SIZE 10
mpirun -np 6 ./myexe def.mtx def.txt -SIZE 10
mpirun -np 8 ./myexe def.mtx def.txt -SIZE 10
mpirun -np 10 ./myexe def.mtx def.txt -SIZE 10
mpirun -np 2 ./myexe qas.mtx qas.txt -SIZE 10
mpirun -np 4 ./myexe qas.mtx qas.txt -SIZE 10
mpirun -np 6 ./myexe qas.mtx qas.txt -SIZE 10
mpirun -np 8 ./myexe qas.mtx qas.txt -SIZE 10
mpirun -np 10 ./myexe qas.mtx qas.txt -SIZE 10
```

If you have `bash` v4+, you can replace `2 4 6 8 10` with `{2..10..2}`.

---

Just for fun, and because I have never tried doing nested calls to **GNU Parallel**, you can do that as a one-liner like this:

```
parallel -j1 "parallel -j1 -I // echo mpirun -np // {} {.}.txt -SIZE 10 ::: 2 4 6 8 10" ::: *mtx

mpirun -np 2 abc.mtx abc.txt -SIZE 10
mpirun -np 4 abc.mtx abc.txt -SIZE 10
mpirun -np 6 abc.mtx abc.txt -SIZE 10
mpirun -np 8 abc.mtx abc.txt -SIZE 10
mpirun -np 10 abc.mtx abc.txt -SIZE 10
mpirun -np 2 def.mtx def.txt -SIZE 10
mpirun -np 4 def.mtx def.txt -SIZE 10
mpirun -np 6 def.mtx def.txt -SIZE 10
mpirun -np 8 def.mtx def.txt -SIZE 10
mpirun -np 10 def.mtx def.txt -SIZE 10
mpirun -np 2 qas.mtx qas.txt -SIZE 10
mpirun -np 4 qas.mtx qas.txt -SIZE 10
mpirun -np 6 qas.mtx qas.txt -SIZE 10
mpirun -np 8 qas.mtx qas.txt -SIZE 10
mpirun -np 10 qas.mtx qas.txt -SIZE 10
```

The outermost instance of `parallel` iterates over the `mtx` files, while the inner instance iterates over the number of processes. Both use `-j1` so that `parallel` only starts one job at a time and doesn't introduce any extra parallelism itself.

Comment: Thanks. Bravo... this is what i was looking for. The third argument -size 10..... The number 10 changes with each pair of files (.mtx,.txt). Should i make a text file and store the sizes of each pair of these files. for example abc.mtx abc.txt  100 ..........qas.mtx qas.txt 149...and so on. Each time program execute with the pair of files and read the corresponding size from text file by matching name...I want to ask what will be the best solution for that ?.....Thanks again...:)

Comment: I have updated the script and the control file format - please take another look.

Comment: Awesome...i am just trying to run above script on mac.. but it gives me an error. script.sh line 9: jobs No such file or directory. Although i have created the file (jobs.rtf) in the same directory and executed the the script like ./script.sh jobs.rtf ./new.....I have tried running sample scripts to make sure they work.

Comment: No! RTF files contain codes to print in bold, to change font and centre text. They are for word processing not scripts. I am not at my Mac but there is an option called `Make plain text` on the menu of `TextEdit` - maybe the `View` menu. You need to click that and also preferably remove the `.rtf` extension.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but i have also tried with .txt its still the same error...i have tried ./script.sh jobs.txt ./new and bash script.sh jobs.txt ./new....

Comment: Please click `edit` under your original question and paste in your script and click `{}` in the Formatting toolbar and also paste in your `jobs` file so I can see what's gone wrong.

Comment: Please have a look on the updated question. THANKS :)

Comment: Ok, if you want to pass the name of the `jobs` file to the script, you need to change the last line of the script to how it is shown in my updated answer.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `./new` parameter. At the moment, it is ignored. What should it do?

Comment: Thanks it works. But it only take first file and run it with 2,4,6,8,10 processes. Echo showed the exact output how i want my execution to be like but actual code only runs on the first file.

Comment: Please click `edit` again and make sure you show the **actual** code and the **actual** `jobs` file and the **actual, corresponding** output. It's really hard to debug something I can't see properly. Thanks.

Comment: I can't see what's wrong. Can you run `file jobs.txt` and `file script.sh` and paste the output please? Also `cat -vet jobs.txt` and `cat -vet script.sh`

Comment: It's a mystery. Last try... please run again with `-xv` option to `bash` so it shows you each command before running it... `bash -xv script.sh jobs.txt`

Comment: Please see edit 4...I dont know why it stops after reading first pair of files, although echo shows correct commands and include all data files.

Comment: I can only imagine your MPI program is reading and consuming the lines from `jobs.txt` and when you use `echo` the MPI doesn't run and therefore doesn't consume the lines. I'll change the code to read the lines of `jobs.txt` into an array where MPI can't consume them... hold on.

Comment: BRAVO..it works now...i really appreciate your help... Thanks again :)